# Is there a way to disable throttling on AppFabric

Tags: windows, appfabric

AppFabric has a concept called 'throttling':

> When physical memory becomes low on a Windows Server AppFabric cache host, the cache host can enter a state called throttling. The cache cluster will not write data to any cache that resides on a throttled cache host until the available physical memory increases to resolve the throttled state.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921030.aspx

That is not a problem on our servers because we can dedicate one to just handle AppFabric, but we do want to run full setup on a local developers machines as well. And that creates a problem because these machines no matter how much RAM they have will eventually run out of it that leads to AppFabric throttling and whole web application simply stops to work (as we are using AppFabric to hold our session state).

Any ideas is there a way to disable this throttling or maybe how to reserve some % of memory for it's process ?